# codefirst, renaming table, trigger error

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

I have my project that is a Xamarin.Forms app, with a Azure SQL Database and an Azure Mobile App Service.

I am using code-first to create the database.

Now I want to rename a class "Customer" to "Company".
The migration is done correctly, the existing table is renamed.

However, there is a trigger, created automatically, that is renamed as well, but the table name that is uses is not modified.  So the triggers doesn't work anymore.

I suppose the trigger exists because of the "ServiceTableColumn" convention added to the modelbuilder.

This is the generated migration code:

```
public partial class rename_customer_to_company_step_1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Customers", newName: "Companies");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Companies", newName: "Customers");
    }
}
```

This is the script for the trigger (after executing the above migration):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_dbo_Customers_InsertUpdateDelete] 
ON [dbo].[Companies]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 

BEGIN 

UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]
SET [dbo].[Customers].[UpdatedAt] = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME()) FROM INSERTED 
WHERE inserted.[Id] = [dbo].[Customers].[Id] 
END
```

As you can see, the table itself has been renamed (ON [dbo].[Companies]
), but the contents of the triggers still references the previous table name (UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]).
Of course the trigger does not work.

How can I have the trigger modified correctly?  Is the trigger really necessary?  Can I get rid of these triggers?

Any ideas how to correct this?  I prefer not to update the triggers manually, why am I using code-first migrations if I need to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Joris

Answer (score 0):

If the code-first migration didn't do it, you will have to edit the code-first migration file or update the triggers yourself.  The triggers are relatively easily done if this is a one-time thing.  See chapter 3 of the Zumo Book at http://aka.ms/zumobook for details on this.